# AWS CodeBuild batch build - access artifacts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I've set up a build job that uses batch builds.

2 batches will build something, upload to S3 and output the location in a json file.

The last batch is supposed to pick up the two json files and use them in some further things.

**My problem:** I can't find the artifacts in the last job.

When I use ls in the first 2 jobs, they are there - but not in the last one.

Here is my buildspec, with unimportantt parts removed.

```
version: 0.2
batch:
  fast-fail: true
  build-graph:
  - identifier: template_examplehook 
  - identifier: s3_checkbucketencryptionhook
  - identifier: stackset 
    buildspec: automation/assemble-template.yaml
    depend-on:
    - template_examplehook
    - s3_checkbucketencryptionhook
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      python: 3.7
  pre_build:
    commands:
    - echo "Starting ..."
    - ...

  build:
    commands:
    - echo "Building with $(python --version)"
    - cd $CODEBUILD_BATCH_BUILD_IDENTIFIER
    - ---
    - echo $S3_URI_PACKAGE > hash.json
    - ---
  post_build:
    commands:
    - echo Build completed on $(date)
artifacts:
  files:
  - '*/hash.json'
```

---

I expected to find the hash.json file in their respective folders but they don't exist in the last batch job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update after talking to our AWS tech support:

Unexpected behaviors, it should work as we thought it would, but it doesn't.

We ended up rewriting it and went with two different build steps.